# Is there a way to password protect my external drive and be compatible with both Windows and OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, external-hard-drive, passwords

I have an external hard drive (HD-PXTU2 Series). I used it for more than 6 months now, what I liked about it was its password protect utility that comes together with the drive. However the problem is the password protect utility is not compatible with OS X (I'll be regularly transferring data between OS X and Windows). Is there a way to password protect my external drive that is compatible with both Windows and OS X?

Comment: It's Mac, not MAC. ;)

Comment: And in this context, it's OS X, not Mac, @musicfreak. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads) is an encryption tool that is available for linux, mac and windows !

Comment: but if i understand correctly it must be installed on the computers that is going to decrypt it. Are there any solutions that would just require plugging it in?

Comment: @Stucko, see TrueCrypt's [Portable Mode](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable).

Comment: @Arjan: Portable Mode doesn't work for OS X, right?

Comment: @Stucko: TrueCrypt is the only somewhat comfortable cross-platform encryption solution that *exists*.

Comment: @Daniel, many applications on OS X can be run right out of their installation image, without actually installing them. I've not tested, but are you sure TrueCrypt really needs to be copied to the hard disk to use it?

Comment: @Arjan TC includes MacFUSE, although I was just able to extract `TrueCrypt.app` from the `Archive.bom.gz` and run it without a proper installation. TC itself was never installed on my machine, but MacFUSE is. Don't know if it's required, though.

Comment: Thanks guys, will try soon, will update you guys on whether it can run without proper installation.

Comment: I ran the TrueCrypt 7.0a Mac OS X.dmg and it simply installed truecypt on the MAC. Its fine for my case since ill be regularly using it. I even partitioned my drive using truecrypt ( i now have a FAT,NTFS, Mac os extended partitions)